# Class ArrayList loses variables after leaving whileloop

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, arraylist

I am creating a algorithm that removes names from a database that are parts of strings. I'm using a JDBC client to get all the values and saving them in an ArrayList. But for some reason some variables loose their values after leaving the `while(resultset.next())` loop

```
public void getAllReqInfo(){
    //ArrayList from the class "req"
    reqArrayList = new ArrayList<req>();
    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM req";
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (resultSet.next()){
            //class with all the columns from the database
            req req = new req(resultSet.getInt("id"),
                              resultSet.getString("comments"));

        reqArrayList.add(req);

        //Comments != null
        System.out.println(reqArrayList.get(0).getComments());

        //Id != null
        System.out.println(reqArrayList.get(0).getId());


        } // End of while

        //Comments == null
        System.out.println(reqArrayList.get(0).getComments());

        //Id != null
        System.out.println(reqArrayList.get(0).getId());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The "req" class is an autogenerated class with getter and setter methods.

I have no clue why that's the case in anyway ty for any help I can get

Answer (score 1):

`reqArrayList.get(0)`

You're only ever printing out the first req, in the loop and after the loop.

To dump out the whole lot, do

```
for (req myReq:reqArrayList){
    System.out.println(myReq.getId()+" "+myReq.getComments());
}
```

Comment: I tested every single value still the same